# Lambda expressions in JSP files will not compile

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I've tried most of the suggestions mentioned on stackoverflow but haven't come across a solution yet. The error I'm being presented with is the following.

```
An error occurred at line: 379 in the jsp file: /application-new-project_process.jsp
Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
```

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2** and have applied these settings.

`Project Structure` → `Project`, `Project SDK` to `1.8 (java version "1.8.0_102")`

`Project Structure` → `Project`, `Project Language Level` to `8.0 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

`Settings` → `Build, Execution, Deployment` → `Compiler` → `Java Compiler`, `Project bytecode version` to `1.8`

`Settings` → `Build, Execution, Deployment` → `Compiler` → `Java Compiler`, `Target bytecode version` to `1.8`

I'm using **Tomcat v8.0.36** and have the following for JSP servlets.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>compiler</param-name> 
        <param-value>modern</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name> 
        <param-value>1.8</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name> 
        <param-value>1.8</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>suppressSmap</param-name> 
        <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the Tomcat instance run in a Java8 JVM?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes I have just confirmed this.

Comment: Is it coming from the server or from IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2, tomcat apache-tomcat-8.5.8, following changes are sufficient for me:
1. Change following file: apache-tomcat-8.5.8\conf\web.xml
2. Modify configuration for

```
 <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
```

3. Add following init params:

   <init-param>
     <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
     <param-value>1.8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
     <param-value>1.8</param-value>
   </init-param>

Finish.

Comment: This is actually correct, my issue was that I modified the configuration for the wrong servlet.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was using Eclipse Oxygen and had the same problem. Your solution solved it.

Comment: Using Spring STS 3.9.4, made change in Package Explorer under `Servers/Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config/web.xml` and solved for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

An updated answer for those using Spring Boot and Tomcat. Since there is no XML configuration file for Tomcat in Spring Boot/MVC, I adapted code linked from [these spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) to create a customizer bean in my base Application class. Fixes problems caused by using Java 8 syntax in JSPs in both  IntelliJ and Gradle CLI.

If you use **Spring 1.x**, add a EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer bean:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
        JspServlet servlet = tomcat.getJspServlet();
        Map<String, String> jspServletInitParams = servlet.getInitParameters();
        jspServletInitParams.put("compilerSourceVM", "1.8");
        jspServletInitParams.put("compilerTargetVM", "1.8");
        servlet.setInitParameters(jspServletInitParams);
    };
}
```

If you use **Spring 2.x**, add a WebServerFactoryCustomizer bean:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return (WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>) factory -> {
        Map<String, String> jspServletInitParams = factory.getInitParameters();
        jspServletInitParams.put("compilerSourceVM", "1.8");
        jspServletInitParams.put("compilerTargetVM", "1.8");
        factory.getJsp().setInitParameters(jspServletInitParams);
    };
}
```